# How to capitalize every other character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want the program to return ' mahir ' as 'MaHiR', I have got MHR but how do I get 'a' and 'h' at their usual place ?

I have already tried slicing but that does not work

```
s = 'mahir'
a = list (s)
c = a[0:5:2]
for i in range (len(c)):
        print (c[i].capitalize(),end = " ")
```

Answer (score 4):

Python's strings are immutable, calling `c[i].capitalize()` will not change `c[i]`, and therefore will not change `s`, to modify a string you must create a new one out of it, you can use `str.join` with a generator expression instead:

```
s = 'mahir'

s = ''.join(c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c for i, c in enumerate(s))

print(s)
```

Output:

```
MaHiR
```

If you want to do it using slicing, you could convert your string to a list since lists are mutable (but the string approach above is better):

```
s = 'mahir'
l = list(s)
l[::2] = map(str.upper, l[::2])
s = ''.join(l)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
MaHiR
```

Comment: what does the map do ?

Comment: @Saturn It applies a function to the elements of a collection, in this case it's applying `str.upper` to the list `l[::2]` (upper-casing them).

Comment: @Saturn If you're more familiar with comprehensions, it's the same as `(str.upper(x) for x in l[::2])`